# UILocalNotification showing Xcode project name

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uilocalnotification

When I send a UILocalNotification the title of the notification is the project name I have in Xcode, how can I change the `packageTracker` to something else?

Here is how I am sending the notification

```
  UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc]init];
  notification.alertBody = @"Test Local Notification";
  notification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:1];
  notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be tied to the Bundle Display Name. Goto your Info.plist and change (or add the Key "Bundle Display Name" or "CFBundleDisplayName" for raw Key) and add a new name.